# Express restrict routes to user roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating a nodejs & express with mongoDB application that requires a company and a user to register, when you fill a registration form, it will as if you are a company or just a normal user.

A model for that is

```
iscompany: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
},
```

I created a middleware to check if the person is a company, and this is the middleware

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user.iscompany) {
      return res.status(401).json({
          msg: "you should be a company to access this. authorization denied",
      });
    }

    next();
};
```

then i imported the middleware in the routes i wanna use it on, and this is the code.

```
const role = require("../../middleware/role");
const User = require("../../models/User");
const Company = require("../../models/Company");
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

//@route GET api/company/me
//@desc get current users profile
//access Private
router.get("/me", auth, role, async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const company = await Company.findOne({
            user: req.user.id,
        }).populate("user", ["avatar", "fullname"]);
        if (!company) {
            res.status(400).json({
                msg: "no company found",
            });
        }
        res.json(company);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.message);
        res.status(400).send("server error");
    }
});
```

I don't understand what when wrong, it's allowing both companies and non-companies to access the route.

Any help?

Comment: didn't solve the problem, that was a typo when i asked a question, not what i coded in the app

Answer (score 1):

I have a problem with this

```
    if (!req.user.iscompany) {
      return res.status(401).json({
          msg: "you should be a company to access this. authorization denied",
      });
    }

    next();
};
```

why not declare your function before trying to export it other than exporting the whole function body at once right inside module.exports.

Try using an arrow function, something like this.

```
const auth = (req, res, next) => {
if(!req.user.iscompany){
    return res.status(401).json({
        msg: "You should be a company to access this. Authorization denied",
    })
}
next();

module.exports = auth // for just exporting a single file   
module.exports = {
    auth // for exporting multiple files. This is a shorthand syntax the
         // property name must relate to the function name.
}

// Then you can now import  into your router file and require it for single file

const auth  = require('../middleware/auth')

// you can do this for multiple file 

const {auth, if any} = require('../middleware/auth')
```

I think that should be the problem, try this out.